# How to use wdBorderBottom with VBA, it is showing up as Empty

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba, ms-access-2013

Why is **wdBorderBottom** showing up as empty?

I want to do this:

```
Set rowNew = oAdjustHereTable.Rows.Add    
rowNew.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
```

*I am looking for an example of how to set MS Word table cell borders that works with office 2013*

When I user the debugger it shows wdBorderBottom as Empty.

Using: MS Access 2013. It looks like it is outdated or a bug or something.
  I have tried lots of examples from the web and nothing looks to be working.

The constants are here, but using the constant (-13) did not look to work, it did not change the border.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821589.aspx

Comment: In which IDE are you working? It is possible that you don't have all the "enum" and constants defined. So you can replace it with its actual value (`-3` and not `-13`) : `Const wdBorderBottom = -3 (&HFFFFFFFD)` and `Const wdLineStyleSingle = 1`, so your line will be `rowNew.Borders(-3).LineStyle = 1`

Comment: @R3uK the IDE is MS Access 2013 - i.e. the built in IDE.  The basic issue is I am unable to find any examples that work, that set the cell border. ... yes, -3 not -13. will look into the constants some more, but it looks like it is "Empty" for a reason.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the Microsoft Word Object library set? Do you have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module? If no, you should have them.

Comment: @eddyparkinson : As @Andre451 said, if you don't have a value for a constant coming from Word in another Office app, you need to check your references and add the one to `Microsoft Word Object Library`

Comment: @Andre451 that solved. Do you want to add it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference to the **Microsoft Word Object library** was not set, therefore `wdBorderBottom` was undefined.

To avoid such errors, add [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to the top of your script, it enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared variables/constants already at compile time.

To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.